# Clear the cache of a record that is updated in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I use Rails.cache.fetch(method_name, :expires_in => 15.minutes) to cache the data. When i update a column, the updated column is displayed in the page only after 15 mins. Is there a way i can clear the cache of the updated record only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the entire cache using `Rails.cache.clear`.

To clear a single entry, use `Rails.cache.delete(method_name)`.